# ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation Failing

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-compilation

I have an ASP.NET project set to utilize dynamic compilation - it has been set for almost a year now and no large changes to the project have been made. Randomly today, the pages have stopped compiling when I visit them... I can completely remove the code from a page and it still renders fine....

What could be causing the project to no longer dynamically compile? Is there something I can look at to determine if some setting was changed?

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not getting errors - I change my code and nothing takes place when I refresh the page. I have tried from multiple machines, cleared caches, the whole bit. So basically I change the code behind but it is not reflected when I refresh the page, because it is not compiling

Comment: Are you sure you're changing files at the server you're browsing to? Perhaps a webfarm where one machine isn't used? Or an old webserver migrated away from?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the cached files which are stuck in the temporary asp.net files folder (c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0...\temporary asp.net files) are used when the page no longer compiles.  Deleting the items in that folder and restarting your appdomain (or IIS) will usually clear that up - then you'll have to find out what's causing the compilation failure.  If you try and build the solution in visual studio, it should give you an indication of where the problem is.

Comment: I believe this was actually it - sadly I had to give up because I do not have admin rights (or any rights, really) to the web servers. The next morning I checked with our network administrator and was informed that it was a server issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I had to give up because I do not have admin rights (or any rights, really) to the web servers. The next morning I checked with our network administrator and was informed that it was a server issue. Thanks anyway everyone!